# How do I make my elementor template in wordpress work on every single page by default?

Tags: wordpress, templates, default, blogs, elementor

I am new to wordpress, I just bought a host and all that for my blog. When I make a template in elementor how do I make that page show up as default on all my blog pages? It works for the front page, then when I click on a blog post it goes back to the theme that is active, which I cant customize and its ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You may need Elementor pro im not sure if free has it but this is your solution:

https://elementor.com/blog/single-archive-builder/